# How post part of Jenkins console output in Slack via Post Build Task?

Tags: jenkins, slack, console-output

I have my Jenkins job with Post Build Task Plugin, Slack Plugin, publish JUnit result report Plugin.

I use Post Build Task Plugin to find some text in console output and when use Slack webhook and curl to post it when this text always same.

Can I post dynamic text?

For example:

Is it possible to get just part of console output (from one standard word or few words to another standard word or few words and not including the last one) ?

And then set all this like Jenkins Environment Variables, so I can use it in curl?

Can someone help me with script if this possible to do? I'm not programmer so it's really difficult for me.

Or maybe you know some another way?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: possibly the answer here ...  https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/5205/post-jenkins-build-console-output-to-slack